# Save item variable with Button Click

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, svelte

I want to create a web app which displays a number of customers from an API, and when I click on a customer, additional information for that customer will be shown.

So far I've fetched my API data as an array, created a list, and a button for each item in the array. Now when I push a customer button I want to call my API again but with the id as a parameter to access specific information about that customer.

However, to do so I need to save the "id" variable from the button that I pushed and I don't understand how to implement that.

This is what my app looks like (in Svelte)

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    
  let customers = []

  onMount(() => {
    fetch('https://europe-west3-gcp-task-346814.cloudfunctions.net/customer-function-1/getCustomer')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => customers = result)
  })
    
  function handleClick() {
        
  }
    
</script>


{#each customers as customer (customer.id)}
<h2>
    <button on:click={() => handleClick()}>
    {customer.name}
  </button>
</h2>   

<p>
    id: {customer.id}
</p>
<hr>
{/each}
```

Note that I'm rather new to JS and HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the code below. Basically you need to pass the customer that you get from the iteration to the `handleClick` function.

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    
  let customers = []

  onMount(() => {
    fetch('https://europe-west3-gcp-task-346814.cloudfunctions.net/customer-function-1/getCustomer')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => customers = result)
  })
    
  function handleClick(customer) {
        // here you have access to the customer id by doing customer.id
        console.log(customer)
  }
    
</script>


{#each customers as customer (customer.id)}
<h2>
    <button on:click={() => handleClick(customer)}>
    {customer.name}
  </button>
</h2>   

<p>
    id: {customer.id}
</p>
<hr>
{/each}
```

The code changed:

```
<button on:click={() => handleClick(customer)}>
```

and

```
function handleClick(customer) {
     console.log(customer)
}
```

Comment: Hahaha, to think the solution was that easy. I thought I tried this but must have made something wrong... Thank you so much!

Comment: The beginning is always the hardest part, but you are on your way. Good luck and good work!